# How to set cookie in Magento

Tags: magento

i am trying to set a cookie for the users who signup with the newsletter pop in magento home page

i have a pop in magento homepage with a newsletter subscription option when user subscribes to the newsletter a cookie is set to that the newsletter will not show him on next visit

here is the code how am setting the cookie

```
<?php
$value=$_POST['newslettertext'];
setcookie("EmailCookie", $value);
setcookie("EmailCookie", $value , time()+86400,"/");  
function gotopage($url)
{
    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">";
    echo "window.location = '".$url."'; \n";
    echo "</script>";
}

$url="http://abc.com";
gotopage($url);

?>
```

the above code sets a coookie

after subscription the user redirects to the same page
there i have check if cookie is set then the popup code executes otherwise there will be non popup

but its still showing the popup after subsscription

am using this code to check cookie

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['EmailCookie'] ) )
{
//popup code goes here
}
?>
```

where am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 32):

```
require_once 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
$cookie->set('cookiename', 'cookievalue' ,time()+86400,'/');
```

here is the answer

Comment: The period should not include current time.
It should be `$cookie->set('cookiename',  'cookievalue' , 86400, '/');`

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($name, $value, $period, $path, $domain, $secure,$httponly);
```

There are 7 parameters where name and value are mandatory; other parameters are optional and can be set as null. Let’s see it one by one.

```
$name= Cookie name

$value= Cookie Value

$period= Cookie expire date (by default the period is set as 3600 seconds)

$path= Cookies path

$domain= Cookies domain

$secure= Cookies Security

$httponly= Http only when yes
```